# Update JSON string value using PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, updates

I have a column which is varchar type, but inside I have json string values like

```
{"namme":"john", "email":"j@gmail.com", "cep":"0000"}
```

I want to update all rows changing "namme" for "name" like this:

```
{"name":"john", "email":"j@gmail.com", "cep":"0000"}
```

I've tried a query like this :

```
update lista_distribuicao
set mycolumn = mycolumn::jsonb - 'namme'
                          || jsonb_build_object('name',
                                                mycolumn->'namme')
```

Bu I get the following error:

> [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb - unknown Dica: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, the only thing missing is the here :

`json_build_object('name',mycolumn::jsonb->'namme')`

Working example :

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    te varchar
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{"namme":"john", "email":"j@gmail.com", "cep":"0000"}');

UPDATE test
SET te = te::jsonb - 'namme' || jsonb_build_object('name', te::jsonb->'namme');

SELECT te
FROM test;
```

Be careful, running this query twice will set the **name** column to NULL